# Blank list dropdown from mysql query into php

Tags: php, mysql

When I am trying the code below, I get a blank dropdown.
Is there anything wrong with this piece of code?

```
<?php
include ("Connect.php");

$db = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
?>
<div class="label">Select Customer Name:</div>
<select name="CustomerName">
<option value = "">---Select---</option>
<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `CustomerName` FROM `tafileuploadmappinghistory`");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name);
while ($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<option value='$name'></option>";
}
$stmt->close();
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Your missing text value in option element <option value='$name'>$value</option>

Comment: Oh! Wow. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update this one line from

```
echo "<option value='$name'></option>";
```

to

```
echo "<option value='$name'>$name</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in while loop for fetch your data

```
while($stmt->fetchAll()) {

 }
```